# Survey Gopher serving somewhat stale SF survey

Tags: discussion, status-completed, advertising

The Server Fault Annual User Survey 2012 Ad is still in rotation. When I click on it, I am informed that the survey is currently closed.

Comment: Survey Gopher is probably busy beating up a groundhog what owes him some money... (alternative answer: "Dude they hired a *gopher* - you get what you pay for!")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ad has been removed from rotation.

We just can't take our eyes off the gophers for a second or they misbehave. ):

Comment: Thanks! Now I've typed the word 'survey' so frequently that it has lost all meaning and cannot possibly be spelled correctly.